# Check whether parent contains ChildNodes

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a parent and a child node under it.
If the parent contains >=1 childnodes then it should confirm with "helllooo" otherwise if the parent does not have any childnodes then it should confirm with "hi"

But however, it does not work that way. It sometimes displays "hi" and other times "helllooo".

Here is the code:

```
function childnode() {
  var treeViewData = window["<%=items.ClientID%>" + "_Data"];

  //if (treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value != ""){
  var selectedNode = document.getElementById(treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value);
  if (selectedNode.childNodes.count >= 0) {
    return confirm("heloo");
  }
  else {
    return confirm("hi");
  }

  return false; // don't send form
}
```

Comment: In your text, you say it should respond with "heloo" if the count is >= 1, but your code has >= 0. Is that a typo?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? regarding what?

Comment: @NickVanderPyle yes thats a typo, changed it to 1

Comment: `childNodes.length` I believe.... The name `count` is not used in the DOM.

Comment: Do you have an example html fragment that causes the intermittent problem? Also, which browsers have you tested with?

Comment: @NickVanderPyle I tested with firefox

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I tried .length but it does not work the way I want it

Comment: @user1047883 well `count` doesn't work the way you want either, and has the disadvantage of ... not existing.

Comment: @Domenic I know that. I just tried it out. I changed it back to Length

Comment: @user1047883 - please do not edit errors in your question as answerers point them out to you; it makes the answer look wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely you are running into the difference between *nodes* and *elements*. *Nodes* can also be, e.g. text nodes or whitespace nodes. You probably want elements.

You also have the issue where there is no such property as `count` on a `NodeList`. You are probably looking for `length`.

Try `selectedNode.children.length` instead of `selectedNode.childNodes.count`.

(Also, your variable `selectedNode` is misnamed: `document.getElementById` returns an element, not a node.)

Comment: selectedNode.childElements.length does not work. The event does not get fired at all.

Comment: it displays "hi" for both nodes. First node only consists of parentnode and seconde node consist of parent node and child nodes

Comment: Please repro on JSfiddle then.

Comment: @Domenic - so children will return all childNodes with nodeType === 1? Neat.   Also, am I reading this right that it's only supported in IE9 ?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.children

Answer (score 0):

You want the `length` property, not the `count` property.  Also, I think you meant `> 0`, instead of `>= 0`

```
var selectedNode = document.getElementById(treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value);
if (selectedNode.childNodes.length > 0) {
    return confirm("heloo");
}
```

This will tell you whether there are *any* child nodes, including text nodes.  If you want to know whether there are any child nodes that are elements, you'd look at the [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType) property.

```
var selectedNode = document.getElementById(treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value);
var children = selectedNode.childNodes;
var anyChildElements = false;

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
   if (children[i].nodeType === 1) {
       anyChildElements = true;
       break;
   }

if (anyChildElements) {
    return confirm("heloo");
}
```

Comment: I pasted the exact same code, but it does not do anything. When click on a button it does not show me the confirmations box

Comment: The event is not getting fired at all

Comment: @user1047883 - what event?  length is a property.

Comment: I mean the function. I set a breakpoint there to see if it is getting fired. But no it is not

Comment: @user1047883 - well I don't know why your function isn't getting fired.  My answer was about fixing what was **inside** of the function

Comment: I tried you code, and it never makes anychildelements true even if the parentnode contains 2 child nodes.

Comment: Have you debugged this in the chrome debugger / firebug?  Have you inspected `selectedNode` to see that it's actually giving you what you expect?